# Enabling Hibernate filters inside a servlet filter in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

I am working on a multi-tenant application which means I need to be able to filter API responses based on the organization account that owns the requesting user profile. In our model, this is referred to as a `Tenant`. I have working Hibernate filters in place which let me control the scope of my resulting queries so that a user under `tenantId` of "foo" will only see rows in associated models which are also owned by foo.

The challenge I have is that I am having to enable this filter from within the scope of a controller method - and so am putting the code at touch-points within the associated model services. This seems like a candidate for a Servlet filter but that does not seem to work.

To implement, I added a public `enableFilter` method to an `@Transactional` service which uses its internal repository reference to enable the filter against my Hibernate session. I then  `@Autowired` this into my servlet filter so I can pickup the tenant associated for the currently requesting user and enable the Hibernate filter accordingly.

The problem is, this doesn't work. It seems that the Hibernate session is either not active or is reset before the actual service does any work. The ressulting queries with the servlet filter enabled do not include my tenant filtering. Enabling those filters within my services does so I know the filters themselves are correct. Is there something I am missing or am I going to have to enable these filters further up the food chain of my request processing?

Comment: The filters will only be enabled for the `enableFilter` method. They are associated with a `Session` which is destroyed after the transaction completes (unless you also have an opensessioninview filter applied BEFORE your enable Filter filter). You should use a filter to set the Tenant in some global resource (a `ThreadLocal` for instance) and then use some AOP to enable filters before a transactions starts (or service methods are called).

Comment: Thanks! Have you seen or are you aware of a working example of this? Just curious before I start down the Google rabbit hole

Comment: Using it in my current project and even before when multi tenant was the new buzzword we used it. I even blogged about it [here](https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/). That code used there is still in production today...